# jirashell throws a "KeyError: u'consumer_key'" and does not start

Tags: python, python-jira

I am new to jira-python and have run into an issue with using jirashell.

jira-python was installed from documentation given here: http://jira.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

When I try to start jirashell using:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-12:~$ jirashell -s https://jira.atlassian.com
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jirashell", line 11, in <module> sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jira/jirashell.py", line 248, in main
  jira = JIRA(options=options, basic_auth=basic_auth, oauth=oauth)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jira/client.py", line 202, in __init__self._create_oauth_session(oauth)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jira/client.py", line 1871, in _create_oauth_session
  oauth['consumer_key'],
KeyError: u'consumer_key'
```

I have also tried to get to a server using basic auth but that returns the same error. Using curl works fine, but I wanted to see the objects that are getting returned and get help as I develop by python-jira integration.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: It should be fixed soon https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/66

Comment: Thank you for the information, @ThePavolC.

In the meantime, I found a workaround that might help if you are using basic auth.
In jirashell.py, go to line 250 and change the line from:
jira = JIRA(options=options, basic_auth=basic_auth, oauth=oauth)
to
jira = JIRA(options=options, basic_auth=basic_auth, oauth=None)

I did not have IPython installed either. Install that with pip and you should be good to go.